# How to find "Most Consistent" performer MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a leaderboard, and I effectively fetch the scores for each user, on each day using the following query:

```
SELECT DATE(a.time) as time, a.userid, SUM(activity_weight) as weight

FROM activity_entries a INNER JOIN users1 u ON u.id = a.userid 

WHERE competitionId = '$competitionId' GROUP BY a.userid, DATE(time) 

ORDER BY time ASC
```

I'm wondering, what would be an effective way to find the "most consistent" performer i.e. the user with the highest average for each day, over the entire duration of the competition.

Thanks so much!

EDIT: Testing this, but having problems with it:

```
SELECT a.userid,
DATE(a.time) as time,
AVG(activity_weight) AS daily_average,

(SELECT a.userid, DATE(a.time) as time,
AVG(AVG(daily_average)) as topAverage
FROM activity_entries a INNER JOIN users1 u ON u.id = a.userid
WHERE competitionId = '$competitionId'
)

FROM activity_entries a INNER JOIN users1 u ON u.id = a.userid
WHERE competitionId = '$competitionId'
GROUP BY userid, time
```

Comment: We can anwser that because we need show create table statements and example data.  can you place an example on sqlfriddle? http://www.sqlfriddle.com

Comment: @RaymondNijland means sqlfiddle.com (no R) in it

Comment: Thanks i mean indeed http://sqlfiddle.com/ without the R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based solely off what you have provided, and assuming that activity_weight is the score for a particular user on a single event, then start with something like the following:

```
SELECT userid,
       time,
       AVG(activity_weight) AS daily_average
FROM activity_entries
GROUP BY userid, time
```

This query returns the average daily score for every user. Now, we need to define "most consistent". If an acceptable definition is "highest average of daily averages", then inner join on the above query as a subquery, selecting `AVG(daily_average)`.

If "most consistent" needs to involve checking the standard deviation, or any more complicated math than just an average, then you should do that in a front-end program, rather than on the database.

**EDIT:** Try this query (or play around with it here: [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6195b/8/0)):

```
SELECT davg.userid,
   SUM(davg.daily_average*davg.num_of_activities)/SUM(davg.num_of_activities) AS weighted_total_average
FROM (
  SELECT userid,
         time,
         AVG(activity_weight) AS daily_average,
     COUNT(*) AS num_of_activities
  FROM activity_entries
  GROUP BY userid, time
) AS davg
GROUP BY davg.userid
ORDER BY AVG(davg.daily_average) DESC
```

The actual details of the math are for you to decide, but here is an example of a weighted average, where days when a competitor participates in a large number of matches are worth more than lazier days.

Comment: So, you're right, it's a fairly simple definition at this point - "highest average, of daily averages". So I will do that. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I'm having a little trouble with the query, I've added what I have to the main post now. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :) Will play around with a few different versions to try get something that works well. Appreciate it!

Comment: Working really nicely. I think I should define most consistent as "highest average, across the highest number of days" - i.e. "streak". I think your query should achieve that right?